# Codeigniter - nested foreach

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a table like this in my database :

| teams | riders |
| --- | --- |
| id_team | id_rider |
| id_rider | id_team |
| name | name |
|  | number |
|  | country |

so what im trying to do is to join those two database, then make a list of each teams and their riders, for example `id_team` 6, have 2 riders, and `id_team` 1, have 1 rider, and then i made view to represent them in my view.

here is my **model** :

```
function group()
{
    $this->db->select('team.name as team_name, rider.*');
    $this->db->from('riders AS rider');
    $this->db->join('teams AS team','team.id_team = rider.id_team');
    $this->db->where('rider.is_deleted','0');
    $this->db->order_by('team.name');
    // $this->db->group_by('team.id_team');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

here is the **controller** :

```
public function riders()
    {

        $template['menuActive'] = 'index';
        $template['menuLoggedIn'] = $this->menuLoggedIn;

        $data['teams_data'] = $this->front->group();

        $this->load->view('front-end/template/header', $template);
        $this->load->view('front-end/list-riders', $data);
        $this->load->view('front-end/template/footer', $template);
    }
```

And here is the **view** :

```
  <?php
      foreach($teams_data as $team)
      {
  ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">              
      <div class="card mv-mb-30" style="padding: 10px 30px; border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;">
        <div class="form-header">
          <div class="mv-title-style-14">
            <div class="text-main mv-mb-20 mv-mt-20"><?php echo $team->id_team; ?> ID_TEAM</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mv-mb-15">
          <div class="col-xs-3" style="border-right: 2px solid #1A1A40;">
            <img src="<?=base_url('/assets/riders/'.$team->image); ?>" alt="" class="block-39-thumb-img">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-9 mv-mb-15">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="zxn mv-mt-5">
                <div class="mv-overflow-ellipsis list-rider"><span>No: <?php echo $team->number; ?></span>Name: <?php echo $team->name; ?></div>
              </div>
              <div class="block-39-price mv-mt-5">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
```

And the view is looks like this :

[image]

As for now riders that have same `id_team` is still displayed on different card and what im trying to do is to display `riders` that had the same `id_team` in one card.

And here what i have tried and tested so far:

**Controller** :

```
$data['teams_data'] = $this->front->getTeam();
$data['riders_data'] = $this->front->getRider();
```

**Model** :

```
function getTeam()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('teams');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
        // return $query->result_array(); got error 'Trying to get property of non-object'
    }

    function getRider()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('riders');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
        // return $query->result_array(); got error 'Trying to get property of non-object'
    }
```

And the **view** :

```
<?php

              foreach($teams_data as $team){

                echo "<li>" . $team->name . "</li>";

                foreach($riders_data as $rider){
                  if($rider['id_team'] == $team['id_team']){ //Line 51
                    echo "<li>" .$rider->name . "</li>";
                  }
                }

              }

            ?>
```

but i ended up getting error like this :

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error
>
> Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
>
> Filename: front-end/list-riders.php
>
> Line Number: 51

i still don't know how to solve this problem, and still searching around and testing for solution, anyone had an solution or maybe an alternative way to do this? anyhelp is really appreciated thank you!.

Comment: Which line causes that problem? What have you tried to resolve it? The given error message does not look related to the title ("nested forech") nor to MySQL itself

Comment: sorry, from my testing, i already shown that line 51, is the one that cause the error, as for the original code, i just don't know how to do another `foreach()` to show the riders based on their `id_team`.

Comment: Whichof these lines is that line 51? What have you tried to check why that given line does not work as expected? I would assume that the variable you are using in that line is of type stdClass, but you try to use it like it was an array

Comment: sorry, it was from **test** part from the **view**, and the line is `if($rider['id_team'] == $team['id_team']){`, which was taken from **model** function `getRider()`.

Comment: If you only want to show the same team riders together, You can use usort() on the team id field to sort the array with respect to team id, this will show the riders with same team id together.